# Length of values does not match length of index in twitter API

Tags: python, pandas, twitterapi-python

im facing an error  while fetching data from twitter API 
I'm trying to save the data into a pandas data frame

THIS IS MY CODE

```
posts = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q =("SpaceX OR SolarCity OR Tesla OR Starlink OR Elon Musk") , 
                      lang="en",since = "2020-04-13",
                      tweet_mode="extended").items(500)
def tweets_to_data_frame(tweets):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets], columns=['tweets'])

        df['id'] = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
        df['date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])


        return df
tweets_to_data_frame(posts)
```

This is my error message:

```
Length of values does not match length of index
```

I think there is some data missing in id or date 
how can I ignore if there is n/a value 
please your advice on that 
thanks

Comment: you need to provide a more detailed exception message.

Comment: @RajatMishra sorry for that i think the problem is with missing maybe some tweets doing have an id or a date

Answer (score 0):

This error message `Length of values does not match length of index` means that one of the columns you are trying to add to the dataframe is not of the same length as the original dataframe. If you want to debug this, you can save the text, id, date, likes, and retweets into separate lists and compare the length.

Looking at your code overall, it would be better to iterate over the cursor. Note that if you keep your existing code, you don't need to cast all of your lists to np.array, as pandas will do that for you.

```
def process_tweet(tweet, default_value=None):
    val = {}
    val['id'] = tweet.id if tweet.id else default_value
    val['created_at'] = tweet.created_at if tweet.date else default_value
    val['likes'] = tweet.favorite_count if tweet.favorite_count else default_value
    val['retweets'] = tweet.retweet_count if tweet.retweet_count else default_value 
    return val

q = "SpaceX OR SolarCity OR Tesla OR Starlink OR Elon Musk"

posts = [process_tweet(tweet) for tweet in 
         tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=(q), lang="en", since="2020-04-13", tweet_mode="extended").items(500)]

df = pd.DataFrame(posts)
```